# Error not a valid identifierd when executing shell script

Tags: shell, shell-script, cygwin, oracle-database

I have the following shell script in order to connect to database and do some tasks.

```
echo Please enter userid:
read USER_NAME

echo "Please enter password:"
read -s PASS   

SID=${ORACLE_SID}

if [ "${ORACLE_SID}" != 'TEST'  ]
then
    sqlplus -s -l $USER_NAME/$PASS@$SID  << EOF
    copy from scott/tiger@orcl insert emp using select * from emp
    exit
EOF

else
    echo  "Cannot copy"
fi
```

However 1when I execute I am getting errors

```
Please enter local Username:
scott
': not a valid identifierd: `USER_NAME
copy_data.sh: line 3: $'\r': command not found
Please enter local Password:
': not a valid identifierd: `
copy_data.sh: line 6: $'\r': command not found
copy_data.sh: line 8: $'\r': command not found
copy_data.sh: line 18: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
copy_data.sh: line 18: `fi'
```

How can I resolve this issue

Debug mode

```
$ bash -x test.sh
+ echo 'please enter username'
please enter username
+ read user_name
vbx
+ echo 'please enter password'
please enter password
+ read -s pass
+ echo
test.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
test.sh: line 12: `else'
```

Comment: Looks like your file has Windows (or Mac) line endings...

Comment: @Mat I have used notepad+ to create the script, how can I make sure it doesn't have Windows line endings? I have tried opening and saving the file using vi editor of cygwin, however it doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks @Mat I have used a tool called WinVi as editor and errors disappeared. However when I execute shell script I am getting error  `syntax error near unexpected token `else'`

Comment: @Polppan have you checked correction as I mentioned ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Indention then you need to add hyphen `-` like `<<-EOF`, then it will work, So Just Do following Changes :

```
sqlplus -s -l $USER_NAME/$PASS@$SID  <<-EOF
copy from scott/tiger@orcl insert emp using select * from emp
exit
EOF
```

I Would Suggest you Some Editor like VIM or Notepad++ which Highlight Syntax error in Colors, if they Wrong.

Example of notepad++ :

[image]

Comment: Rahul, I have tried as you have mentioned, however I am getting the same error message when I am executing shell script.

Comment: You can run script in debug mode like `bash -x script.sh` and give me output in pastbin

Comment: I have edited my question to include the output of script execution in debug mode.

Comment: Have you made change like `<< EOF` to `<<-EOF` and also Space in EOF, if no check copy and paste in script from this page and let me know http://paste.ubuntu.com/6013791/

Comment: Check this is working http://paste.ubuntu.com/6013802/